# Erro ao abrir um arquivo zip no PHP

Tags: php, io

Código:

> echo file_get_contents('zip://arquivos.zip#zipado.txt');

---

Erro de saída:
Aviso do PHP: file_get_contents(): Não foi possível encontrar o wrapper "zip" - você esqueceu
de habilitá-lo quando configurou o PHP? no código shell php online 1

```
Aviso: file_get_contents(): Não foi possível encontrar o wrapper "zip" - você esqueceu de 
habilitá-lo quando configurou o PHP? no código shell php na linha 1 PHP Warning:                     
file_get_contents(zip://arquivos.zip#zipado.txt): Falha ao abrir o fluxo: Não existe esse 
arquivo ou diretório no código shell php na linha 1

Aviso: file_get_contents(zip://arquivos.zip#zipado.txt): Falha ao abrir stream: Não existe tal 
arquivo ou diretório no código shell php na linha 1

Toda vez que tento exibir um arquivo em PHP, ele retorna esse erro e não consigo executar meu 
código porque a única saída é um erro, por favor me ajude!
```

```html
<pre>
    PHP Warning: file_get_contents(): Unable to find the wrapper "zip" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in php shell code on line 1

Warning: file_get_contents(): Unable to find the wrapper "zip" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in php shell code on line 1 PHP Warning: file_get_contents(zip://arquivos.zip#zipado.txt): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in php shell code on line 1

Warning: file_get_contents(zip://arquivos.zip#zipado.txt): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in php shell code on line 1
</pre>
```

Answer (score -2):

olá, qual o caminho do arquivo .zip?

**1 -** *Verifique seu a extensão Zip está instalada no (php.ini)*

**2-** Tente abre assim:

A) `$resultado= file_get_contents('zip://foo.zip#dirName/bar.txt');`

B) `$resultado= file_get_contents('zip://path_to_my.zip#subDir/foo.txt');`

Tem duas opções veja qual te antende melhor. Espero te ajudado